# Change font color in JavaFX via .css file

Tags: css, javafx

Can someone please tell me why **-fx-text-fill** in the below example doesn't work to change the font color? -fx-stroke is something I've tried as well. Thanks!

**Java File:**

```
package SimpleTextFromCSS;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        GridPane rootGP = new GridPane();
        Label centerText = new Label("Sample text.");
        rootGP.getChildren().add(centerText);
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootGP,1200,800);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());

        primaryStage.setScene(mainScene);
        primaryStage.show();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.root{
  -fx-font-family: "Broadway";
  -fx-font-size: 50pt;
  -fx-text-fill: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments (thanks to [@Slaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6395627/slaw)), the `-fx-text-fill` property is not inherited by default, so setting it for your root pane will not allow it to propagate down to the labels in your UI. A possible fix would be to define the property for, say `.label`, but a better approach is to hook into the "theming" functionality of the default style sheet ("modena"). Admittedly, the documentation on this is pretty thin, but reading the comments in the [CSS source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css), particularly at the top of the file, indicate how this is intended to work.

Modena defines a "looked-up color" called `-fx-text-background-color`, which is used for text painted on top of a background filled with `-fx-background-color`. A `Label` is such a text, and the default style sheet sets the text fill of a label to `-fx-text-background-color`.

So one approach is to redefine the `-fx-text-background-color` value:

```css
.root{
  -fx-font-family: "Broadway";
  -fx-font-size: 50pt;
  -fx-text-background-color: blue;
}
```

If you want to be a little more sophisticated, the default value of `-fx-text-background-color` is actually a "ladder", which picks a color depending on the intensity of the background. It is itself defined in terms of three other colors:

- `-fx-light-text-color` (for dark backgrounds, which defaults to white),
- `-fx-mid-text-color` (for light backgrounds, which defaults to a light grey), and
- `-fx-dark-text-color` (for medium backgrounds, which defaults to black).

So if you want a solution that would be visually robust to changes in the background of a label, you could do

```css
.root{
  -fx-font-family: "Broadway";
  -fx-font-size: 50pt;

  -fx-dark-text-color: navy ;
  -fx-mid-text-color: blue ;
  -fx-light-text-color: skyblue ;
}
```

Comment: While this doesn't change the solution, I don't believe the problem is that _modena.css_ adds a background style to labels. Style sheets added to the scene [will override the styles specified by the user-agent style sheet](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introstylesheets). I believe the underlying cause of the OP's problem is that `-fx-text-fill` is [not inherited by default](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introinheritance).

Comment: @Slaw Yes, good point. I updated the answer to be more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

```
Text {
   -fx-fill: blue;
}
```

Can be used to change all Text components in a layout.

```
.root-pane .wrapper Text {
    -fx-fill: blue;
}
```

Also works if you want to specify more specific components like usual css.